# Define default values using EF Core - OnModelCreating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I started migrating from Asp.net MVC to Asp.Net MVC Core, I realized that some things are a little bit different than I expected.
I'd like to know how I can set some propeties like I used to do in EF 6

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();                                                  
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();


    modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("varchar"));
    modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(100));
    modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "Active").Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("char").HasMaxLength(1).IsRequired());
    modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "Excluded").Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("char").HasMaxLength(1).IsRequired());
    modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "RegisterDate").Configure(x => x.IsRequired());
    modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "ChangeDate").Configure(x => x.IsRequired());

    ...
}
```

It seems I can't do it do using EF Core

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{

}
```

Does anyone knows how I can do that?

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)?

Comment: You can enumerate all entities using `builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` and their properties to see if it exists and then configure the model. See "Replacing the default conventions with snake case
" in https://andrewlock.net/customising-asp-net-core-identity-ef-core-naming-conventions-for-postgresql/

Comment: @poke yes I did

Comment: @micnyk I'll check that doc thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you have to call this line for your entities first

```
var entityBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>();
```

Then do the following:

```
entityBuilder.Property(someEntity => someEntity.SomeProperty)
             .HasColumnType("char")
             .HasMaxLength(10)
             .IsRequired();
```

Also have a look at [IEntityTypeConfiguration<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ientitytypeconfiguration-1?view=efcore-2.0) it will help you to keep your DbContext clean. Within your DbContext OnModelCreating Method you will then just call

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new SomeEntityConfiguration());
```

Based on that you can also define a base class for common properties and create a base IEntityTypeConfiguration<> for common properties. Not much magic there but some things are just better defined explicit rather than implicit.

Comment: but it works for only one entity at once, doesn't it? I looking for a way to get all properties of all entities which has type of a string , int or whatever, then set up its maxLength, columnType and etc, as I done using EF 6. I'm still reading the docs to find out how to do it. Thank you anyway

Comment: Yes, this would be per entity configuration. AFAIK what you are trying to do is not possible anymore. As I said, some things are better defined explicit.